# How to setState generically?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a generic OnChange handler:

```
handleOnChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.id]: e.target.value});
}
```

Throws this error:

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IState | 
Pick<IState, "email" | "password"> | ((prevState: Readonly<IState>, props: 
Readonly<LinkDispatchProps>) => IState | ... 1 more ... | null) | null'.
  Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 
'Pick<IState, "email" | "password">': email, password
```

I believe it is because I am typing the State like this:

```
interface IState {
    email: string,
    password: string
}
```

I can get rid of this error by making the interface elements optional, but, of course, that causes errors elsewhere.

How can I dynamically set the state elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that typescript doesn't know that `e.target.id` will contain only valid key names of `IState` interface. Try this:

```js
handleOnChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({
       [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    }  as Pick<IState, keyof IState>);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635

Comment: Thanks Martin. Unfortunately, it is giving the same error.

Comment: Thanks. For those who, like me, are not familiar with Pick and other Utility Types, here is an interesting read: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
handleOnChange: ChagenEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.id]: e.target.value});
}
```